# How to prevent a browser for caching a link?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

I have a user private area and a 'Log off' link:

```
<a href="~/User/Logoff">Log off</a>
```

The problem is that the browser caches this link and does not make a request to the server each time users click on it.

I searched and found a solution that is supposed to turn off caching for the entire page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

But I do not want to turn off caching completely, I only want to make sure that when a user clicks 'Log off' the request would always be made.

Is it possible to tell the browser that this particular link is not cacheable?

Comment: Make it a button and do your log off in the code behind before redirecting to your logoff page (ah just seen the answer - exactly like the answer below has stated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, state-changing HTTP operations shouldn't use the GET verb (like a link). You should consider using a `<form>` that POSTs to an endpoint that logs the user out.

```
<form method="POST" action="~/User/Logoff">
  <button type="submit">Log off</button>
</form>
```

This will never be cached.

If you must use the GET verb, and you're using WebAPI, I believe there are attributes you can decorate your route method with that will disable caching.